# Simplest way to get the number of calls to an MSSQL2000 Server

Tags: performance, sql-server-2000

Does anyone know how one can get the total number of calls to an MSSQL2000 server during a specified time, let’s say 24 hours?

We want figures of how many calls our production machine gets per day, but we can’t find any good tools/strategies for this.

Best regards
Fredrik

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think using SQL Profiler here is overkill in this situation, particularly as it can create a substantial load on the server depending on what you trace. SQL Server exposes the raw values used for its performance counters via the sysperfinfo system table; you should just be able to run this query once each day and subtract the values to work out how many SQL requests you received for the day:

```
SELECT cntr_value 
FROM sysperfinfo 
WHERE object_name = 'SQLServer:SQL Statistics' 
AND counter_name = 'Batch Requests/sec'
```

This will obviously only work if the server is up for the whole day; restarting will reset the number.

Answer (score 1):

You could use SQL Profiler?

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa173918(SQL.80).aspx
http://www.sqlteam.com/article/sql-server-2000-performance-tuning-tools
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/325263

Answer (score 0):

I sloved this another way (all calls are "routed" thru an IIS cluster and I where able to analyze their logs).

Thanx!